# Searching for a Lazy Loading jQuery Slideshow or: hacking cross-slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lazy-loading, slideshow

I am trying to get a jquery slideshow to display images from flickr, fading and scrolling. Everything works fine, except I really need Lazy Loading of the images (just loading the images on demand).

I am currently using jquery.cross-slide ( http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/ ) but unfortunately tobia is not working on the plugin anymore and also does not want to answer to questions.

I found an example of jquery.cycle, where image lazy loading is applied (see http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/add3.html ) is there any chance of hacking this feature into the source of cross-slide or is it not possible due to the architecture of the plugin?
see the code here: https://github.com/tobia/CrossSlide/blob/master/jquery.cross-slide.js#L131

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188331/jquery-cycle-plugin-with-ajax-functionality

Answer (score 9):

For others looking for a slideshow that "lazyloads" images, here are 2 options:

- http://galleria.aino.se/ - great slideshow, lots of options, not really lightweight
- http://reallysimpleworks.com/slideshow/ - simple, works fine. I´m using this one now.

Comment: thanks for the great pointer! unfortunately i need the scrolling from cross-slide, which seems to be not available in Really Simple™ Slideshow

Answer (score 1):

try [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel),
it's lovley (lazyloading possible ..)

Comment: thanks for the pointer, i am trying it out right now. unfortunately it seems like i have to write the transition and scrolling as well as the text-display hook by myself in this case...

Comment: dunno if it really fits your case, auto-scrolling is there, animation is just the move and text-display not implemented there .. but its a nice jQplugin .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted 2 years ago, but jcarouFredSel would work:

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/14/