# JavaScript image slider that will allow more slides to be added after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am currently building an image slider page. The slider loads 10 images, and as the user approaches the end of these 10, it loads 10 more, ad infinitum. Ie like:

```
if (currentSlideNumber = allSlides.length - 2) { get more slides }
```

The new slides are added dynamically as DOM elements - img tags with srcs.

Obviously there are literally countless js slider plugins and options available, but as far as I can tell, none of them were built to handle this kind of usage. How is this typically handled?

**EDIT:**
I was able to get a working solution via [lightSlider](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/). My js function adds img tags inside of li tags, and then calls slider.refresh(), which forces the slider to rescan the DOM and perform the necessary actions on the new DOM elements to add them to the slider.

Comment: Probably you have already seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412015/seaching-for-a-lazy-loading-jquery-slideshow-or-hacking-cross-slide) but just to play safe. =]

Comment: @Alp Yes, I've seen that. Lazy loading isn't exactly what I'm looking for, as I'm handling the XMLHttpRequests to fetch urls in my own function. Also, that thread is 4 years old and many of the plugins are deprecated/not supported anymore. Do you know of a contemporary equivalent?

Comment: I assume you already know [Slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) too. But no harm to mention it again.

Comment: @Alp Yes, I know slick. The docs make no mention of dynamically adding slides.

Comment: Actually there is lazy loading. Check out [source code](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js) line #1303. I think it is close to what you are looking for.

Comment: The idea is the same as with infinite scroll (paul irish). 
Infinite scroll calculates where you are, scrolling wise on he page and if you get above a certain threshold it does an ajax request and pulls more stuff in. What you should do is the same thing - keep track of item(s) in view and if you're at say, 9 do your ajax request.  
The implementation will depend on how the images are actually presented - for instance overlapping versus continuous element (horizontally as well as vertically).

Comment: I'd suggest you have events that trigger once a new image is presented, to avoid the need to calculate anything - works on one item in view type approach. If you have a continuous scrolling slider, you'll have to do the math.

Comment: @RaduAndrei Yes, I know. Loading the images in an infinite scrolling sort of way isn't the problem, it's getting the actual slider to "refresh" and acknowledge the new slides.

Comment: @Alp Ah I see, so I would just have to call exampleSlider.lazyload();?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Let's put it this way.

Library you want to use is [Slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js)

**How are you going to use this ?**

Here is your HTML

```
<div class="slider lazy">
    <div><div class="image"><img data-lazy="someImage.jpg"/></div></div>
    ...
</div>
```

And I think this script will do the trick:

```
$('.lazy').slick({
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but after further investigation, this does not help. All this does is put off actual loading, it doesn't detect newly-added DOM elements. I would like to be able to dynamically add DOM elements and have the slider recognise these newly added elements.

Comment: I was able to find a working solution, check my question for a final edit explaining this.

Comment: Awesome.! Thanks for dropping me a line =]