# Dynamically Load Jquery Slider Images, after Page Loads with Jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unslider

I am using unslider (unslider.com).

It works fine, if I have the images loaded on page load.

However, I want to load the slider, and fill in the slides later, in a function that gets the images from an AJAX call to a server.

The Slider:

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul id="slider-ul">
        <li><img id="slider-img-1" class="bjqs-slide-img" src="" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The slider gets its images from an ajax call (which I have verified is calling data correctly, and $.each function (which seems to be working fine...):

```
$.each(html.listing.photos, function (i, v) {
                    $("#slider-ul").append('<li><img id="slider-img-'+html.listing.data[0].listno+'" class="bjqs-slide-img" src="'+v+'" alt="" /></li>');
                });
```

If I use the dev tool/inspector in chrome, I can see that the slides are populated with images correctly. However the slider is broken. I am assuming because the slides were loaded after the slider code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved it with the lighslider answer in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963316/javascript-image-slider-that-will-allow-more-slides-to-be-added-after-page-load?rq=1

Comment: is there a refresh method for unslider or did you change to lightslider?